# Best solution for generating flat report

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, ssas, multidimensional-cube

I have an SSAS multidimentional cube (sql server 2019) of 350 GB with a retention of 10 years of data.
I noticed that users often use the cube to extract data at the leaf level (Excel tables with multiple columns).

I think that SSAS is not suited for producing these type of reports.

What is the best tool / solution to let users genrate flat reports ? I know that sql is good for that but users aren't sql developers.

Could a PowerBI Model with direct query be more efficient than tha actual SSAS cube ?

Answer (score 0):

> Could a PowerBI Model with direct query be more efficient than tha actual SSAS cube ?

SSAS Multidimensional is *exceptionally bad* at generating large flattened results.  Almost anything will be better.  A PowerBI or SSASS Tabular DirectQuery model is much better, but not ideal for very large extracts.  But be sure to extract through DAX not MDX.  A Paginated Report exported to CSV or Excel is a good choice too.

Comment: Browne I think paginated report is a tool for developers.

Comment: Yes.  The idea there is to publish a Paginated report for them to use to extract the data.  They could filter the data using parameters, but not change what table is used by each report.

Comment: Could also use ssrs to generate reports.